# wpf dependency property add owner

Tags: c#, wpf

В книге Петцольда есть следующий пример:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace Petzold.SetSpaceProperty
{
    public class SpaceWindow: Window
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SpaceProperty;
        public int Space
        {
            set
            {
                SetValue(SpaceButton.SpaceProperty, value);
            }
            get
            {
                return (int)GetValue(SpaceButton.SpaceProperty);
            }
        }

        static SpaceWindow()
        {
            FrameworkPropertyMetadata metadata = new FrameworkPropertyMetadata() { Inherits = true};

            SpaceProperty = SpaceButton.SpaceProperty.AddOwner(typeof(SpaceWindow));
            SpaceButton.SpaceProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(SpaceWindow), metadata);
            Console.WriteLine(SpaceButton.SpaceProperty.GetMetadata(typeof(SpaceWindow)).DefaultValue);
            Console.WriteLine(SpaceProperty.GetMetadata(typeof(SpaceWindow));

        }
    }
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, зачем нужен метод AddOwner у зависимых свойств и в чём разница, между вызовом этого метода и переопределение метаданных для свойства зависимости? Если закомментировать вызов данного метода, программа всё равно выполняется.

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace Petzold.SetSpaceProperty
{
    public class SpaceWindow: Window
    {
        //public static readonly DependencyProperty SpaceProperty;
        public int Space
        {
            set
            {
                SetValue(SpaceButton.SpaceProperty, value);
            }
            get
            {
                return (int)GetValue(SpaceButton.SpaceProperty);
            }
        }

        static SpaceWindow()
        {
            FrameworkPropertyMetadata metadata = new FrameworkPropertyMetadata() { Inherits = true};

            //SpaceProperty = SpaceButton.SpaceProperty.AddOwner(typeof(SpaceWindow));
            SpaceButton.SpaceProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(SpaceWindow), metadata);
            Console.WriteLine(SpaceButton.SpaceProperty.GetMetadata(typeof(SpaceWindow)).DefaultValue);
            //Console.WriteLine(SpaceProperty.GetMetadata(typeof(SpaceWindow));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Сам Петцольд не пишет что ли зачем этот метод нужен? На самом деле это просто — с помощью этого метода свойство зависимости предоставляется для класса, который не является наследником текущего. Т. е. получается SpaceButton и SpaceWindow будут пользоваться одним и тем же свойством зависимостей, что позволит им использовать, например, общие стили.

Comment: "пользоваться одним и тем же свойством".Но как же так, мы же в первом случае создаём второе свойство, а во втором примере свойство одно?

Comment: В какой строчке вы создаете новое DP?

Comment: public static readonly DependencyProperty SpaceProperty;

Comment: В этой строчке нету оператора присваивания вообще. Вам нужно разобраться с базовыми понятиями C#, различать объявление поля и его инициализацию, также понимать отличие типов значений и ссылочных типов. Ни в первом, ни во втором случае новые DP не создаются. В первом случае мы записываем в поле уже существующее DP, объявленное в классе SpaceButton, а во втором случае поле у вас вообще остается неинициализированным. Не спроста ведь вы закомментировали строчку `Console.WriteLine(SpaceProperty.Get...`? Наверняка она NRE выбрасывала? :)